# Hiding and showing Eclipse view programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am showing and hiding Eclipse view with code below. It works perfectly with Eclipse 3.3, but with Eclipse Juno (version 4.3) it's not showing the first time but showing when I fire the event for the second time.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
    .getActivePage();
page.showView(UserView.ID);
page.hideView(page.findView(UserView.ID));
```

Is somebody come across with this situation before?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are not getting it the first time. Check to see if you dont have null pointer errors when you fire it the first time.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
```

can return a `null` if the workbench is not yet loaded.

Comment: Thank you for response, I have try catch block around this code and no exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with the minimized state, so I tried chaging the view's state forcing it to appear after `page.showView(UserView.ID);`

this piece of code got my viewPart to show :

```
page.showView(UserView.ID); 
IWorkbenchPartReference ref = page.getReference(searchResultUI);    
page.setPartState(ref,IWorkbenchPage.STATE_RESTORED); //or STATE_MAXIMIZED
```